# Pytorch tensor multiplication and addition too long on GPU

Tags: profiling, convolution, multiplication, pytorch, tensor

I am having strange profiling results on a FISTA algorithm implemented with pytorch, and running on GPU. I am using the line-profiler tool in a notebook, and before I launch the notebook I export CUDA_LAUNCH_BLOCKING=1 to prevent asynchronous launch of cuda (in order to have a faithful profiling).

Here is the minimal code I am using :

```
x_old = torch.randn(20,64,49,49).cuda()
image = torch.randn(20,1,64,64).cuda()
dico = torch.randn(64,1,16,16).cuda()

def MinimalCode(x_old, image, dico):
    i=1
    z_new=x_old
    while i <= 1000:
        residual = f.conv_transpose2d(z_new, dico) - image
        dx = f.conv2d(residual, dico)
        x_new = f.relu(torch.add(z_new - dx/100, -0.2/100))
        z_new = x_new + torch.mul(x_new - x_old, ((1.25 - 1) / 1.24))
        x_old=x_new
        i+=1
```

I'm only profiling the following code :

```
test = MinimalCode(x_old, image, dico)
```

My profiling results are :

```
Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
 1                                           def MinimalCode(x_old, image, dico):
 2         1          2.0      2.0      0.0      L=100
 3         1          1.0      1.0      0.0      i=1
 4         1          1.0      1.0      0.0      z_new=x_old
 5      1001        777.0      0.8      0.0      while i <= 1000:
 6      1000    4830461.0   4830.5     29.0          residual = f.conv_transpose2d(z_new, dico) - image
 7      1000    2846208.0   2846.2     17.1          dx = f.conv2d(residual, dico)
 8      1000    4998924.0   4998.9     30.0          x_new = f.relu(torch.add(z_new - dx/L, -0.2/100))
 9      1000    3992261.0   3992.3     23.9          z_new = x_new + torch.mul(x_new - x_old, ((1.25 - 1) / 1.24))
10      1000       1610.0      1.6      0.0          x_old=x_new
11      1000        938.0      0.9      0.0          i+=1
```

In the profiling results, I am very surprised of the following lines :

- line #8 : a simple relu applied to simple tensor & operation takes more time than a complex deconvolution (line #6). Mathematically speaking, the complexity of line #8 is way under the one of line #6
- line #9 : same here

Why simple tensor addition and scalar multiplication are taking approximating the same time than a complex convolution ? Is there a way to make this code faster ? I'am missing something in the profiling process ?

Thanks in advance for your help !!

Comment: Can you provide a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example? https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: what version of cuda are you using

Comment: My version of Cuda is : CUDA Version 9.0.176